# form_for HAML каждый элемент в новой строке

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Не получается сделать так, что бы каждый элемент в `form_for` был на отдельной строчке без использования `%br` или оборачивания каждого элемента в `%div`. В чём заключается моя ошибка?

**edit.html.haml**

```
= form_for @profile, url: edit_profile_path do |f|
  %div{:class => 'name-group'}
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name
  %div{:class => 'age-group'}
    = f.label :age
    = f.text_field :age
  = f.submit
```

**profile.scss**

```
.name-group,
.age-group {
  display: block;
}
```

Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Посмотрите, какой html генерится без дивов. Я полагаю, ни у лэйбла, ни у инпута не будет свойств, которые бы делали их блоком. Ну и собственно, в чём проблема - завернуть в див?

Comment: @Василиса Мне кажется, что оборачивать каждый элемент в `div` не очень правильно. Уверен, должен быть способ, при котором каждый элемент дива будет на отдельной строчке. Вот только найти не получается

Comment: Способ есть - назначаете класс каждому инпуту, и в css этому классу ставите `display: block`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как и сказала @Василиса оборачивать каждый элемент в `div` блок - нормальная практика. Так я и поступил, другого способа не нашёл